# Getting the number of criteria met

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

When I run an "advanced search" query, I would like to be able to know for each line returned the number of criteria met. For example, in this query, I'm getting the people whose first name starts with an "A" and last name starts with a "B" :

```
select case when (u.firstname like "A%") then 1 else 0 end + case when (u.lastname like "B%") then 1 else 0 end as criteria_nb, u.ID, firstname, lastname, picture from Users u where u.firstname like "A%" or u.lastname like "B%";
```

Here is what my table Users looks like

```
 ID
 firstname
 lastname
 picture
 nbr_children
```

This works fine. I would just have to order the results by *criteria_nb* and I would get first the users meeting both requirements, then the ones meeting just one.

Now the problem is how to do it on multiple tables. Here I'm trying to get the users having 0 to 10 children and at least one child born in 2017. I have a table named "User_children_years_of_birth" which looks like this:

```
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| user_id       | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year_of_birth | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I first tried this :

```
 select case when (u.children_nbr >= 0 and u.children_nbr <= 10) then 1 else 0 end + case when ((yob.user_id = u.id and (yob.year_of_birth=2017))) then 1 else 0 end as nb_criteres, u.ID, firstname, lastname, picture from Users u  join User_children_years_of_birth yob on (yob.user_id = u.id and (yob.year_of_birth=2017)) where (u.children_nbr >= 0 and u.children_nbr <= 10);
```

This won't work. The INNER JOIN would make the query return the users meeting BOTH criteria. So I'm trying with this syntax (my favorite actually)

```
 select case when (u.children_nbr >= 0 and u.children_nbr <= 10) then 1 else 0 end + case when ((yob.user_id = u.id and (yob.year_of_birth=2017))) then 1 else 0 end as nb_criteres, u.ID, firstname, lastname, picture from Users u, User_children_years_of_birth yob where (u.children_nbr >= 0 and u.children_nbr <= 10) or (yob.user_id = u.id and (yob.year_of_birth=2017));
```

This returns duplicate results, and I don't understand why. However I can see that if a user meets both criteria, they will show up once with "2" as nb_criteria, then "1" as nb_criteria.

Now I'm really confused because first I thought that these two JOIN syntax were equivalent. So can you please

1) explain me these results

2) explain me the difference between both syntax

3) show me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do with that information. !?!?!

Comment: One difference is that the condition in the first, "yob.user_id = u.id and (yob.year_of_birth=2017)" when it is included in the JOIN is applied to all results.  Because in your second result the WHERE contains "(u.children_nbr >= 0 and u.children_nbr <= 10) OR ..."  this will be satisfied any time that condition is met, and that is not the same as the first condition.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to GROUP BY the user and get the sum of the matching children?  If so check out the GROUP BY syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This structure should help you out

EXISTS to check for at least 1 child born in 2017

Having count -- number of kids max 10

```
SELECT ...
From table1 ...
Join table2 ...
Join table3 ...
Where ....
Exists( select 1 from tableforgettingkids where parent = mainqueryparentid and birthdateyear = 2017)
Group by ...
Having count(noofkids) < 11
```